# CSS: border-top on <tbody> not being applied

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm stuck on why the style on the `<tbody>` doesn't seem to be working: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycEHT/)). What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="basket">
        <tr class="head">
            <th class="title">Product</th>
            <th class="price">Unit Price</th>
            <th class="quantity">Quantity</th>
            <th class="total">Total</th>
        </tr>
                    <tr class="item">
            <td class="title"><a href="#">Product 1</a></td>
            <td class="price">&pound;0.30</td>
            <td class="quantity"><input value="2"/></td>
            <td class="total">&pound;0.60</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody class="ordersummary" style="border-top: 3px solid blue;">
            <tr class="subtotal">
                <td colspan="3" class="label">Subtotal</td>
                <td class="value">&pound;0.60                       </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="shipping">
                <td colspan="3" class="label">Shipping</td>
                <td class="value">&pound;0.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="total">
                <td colspan="3" class="label">Total</td>
                <td class="value">&pound;0.60</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/fpJLv/1/)

You need to add:

`table {border-collapse: collapse;}`

Incidentally, you should also separate out your styles from content and put your CSS in a separate stylesheet.

---

### [Alternative Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/fpJLv/)

Add:

`display:block`

To your `tbody`.

Comment: Regarding stylesheets - yes, I just did it this way to emphasise the problem. Why is the `display: block` needed? This previous question doesn't mention it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712946/add-borders-on-tbody

Comment: @Jodes, you may also want to look at using `table {border-collapse: collapse;}` as an alternative

Comment: This breaks the tabular layout: the figures do not appear in the “Total” column.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - see my last comment / revision

Comment: But they do mention "Or, if you're targeting those browsers that don't offer the option to style the tbody with a border, you can target specific cells within the tbody using the following:".

Answer (score 0):

This could probably work:

```
tbody > tr:first-child > td {
    border-top: 3px solid blue;
}
```

BUT! Normal rules about styling HTML with CSS ends at tables.